# CoreData NSFetchRequest error NSInvalidArgumentException in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, xcode8

After updating my project to latest swift syntax (Swift 3) I'm getting an error on performing CoreData fetch request. So the app worked for many months and now it's broken.

So this is how I perform my fetch request.

```
let requestSavedLevel = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LevelEntity")
let levelNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "levelName = %@", levelName) 
requestSavedLevel.predicate = levelNamePredicate 

  do {
     let results = try userDataStack.context.fetch(requestSavedLevel) as? [LevelEntity]
     if (results?.count)! > 0 {
       self.savedLevel = results?.first!

       return results?.first!
     }
    } 
  catch {
      print("\n Error on \(#function): \(error)")
  }
```

The error occurs on a line

> let results = try userDataStack.context.fetch (requestSavedLevel) as? [LevelEntity]

and it immediately takes me to AppDelegate and shows **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

The console prints out message: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (9)'

I have no clue what happened and why the code is no longer working. I've seen other questions about CoreData problems in Swift 3 but that didn't help.

***  EDIT  ***

I tried to find what causes the error and I found next.
My NSManagedObject has these properties 
`extension MyEntity {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest< MyEntity > {
    return NSFetchRequest< MyEntity >(entityName: "MyEntity");
}

@NSManaged public var horizontal: NSObject?
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var shapes: NSObject?

}
```

I want to save the next data to core data:
 var horizontal: [[Int]]
 var name: String
 var shapes: [Int:Shape]

And I do it like this:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyEntity", into: userDataStack.context) as! MyEntity

    entity.name = name
    entity.horizontal = horizontal as NSObject
    entity.shapes = shapes as NSObject

    userDataStack.saveContext()
```

However, error occurs when I try to save the last part which is `entity.shapes = shapes as NSObject`

**Shape** is a custom class, subclass of **NSObject**.

So what I get when I try to fetch data from Core Data, is that **count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (9)'**.

Again, everything has worked great for many month until I updated project to Swift 3.

I tried to use NSArchiver to archive shapes and then assign it to entity.shapes as NSObject, and it works, but if it the only solution then I have to update a lot of code.

Any suggestions why this is not working?

Comment: It's very unlikely that the error occurs in this code (no dictionary is involved). By the way: If the fetch succeeds, the result is guaranteed to be `[LevelEntity]`, you can safely use `as!` and `if (results?.count)! > 0 {` can be replaced with `if !results.isEmpty {`. PS: In Swift 3 the fetch request is supposed to be created with `let requestSavedLevel: NSFetchRequest<LevelEntity> = LevelEntity.fetchRequest()`

Comment: 1) Just tried to change declaration of requestSavedLevel with LevelEntity.fetchRequest(), and now it is not even initialized.
2) I have a breakpoint on a line with try context.fetch, and if I go to next step it takes me to AppDelegate.

Comment: The class method `fetchRequest()` must be implemented in the `NSManagedObject` subclass

Comment: I see, I'll do that and will update post or add a comment.

Comment: So, I regenerated NSManagedObject Subclass and fetchRequest() method has been added by xCode. 
But still getting the same error on try userDataStack.context.fetch(NSFetchRequest)

Comment: But there is no dictionary unless you create the request with dictionary return value. Maybe the real error occurs after returning from that method.

Comment: I have no clue what is wrong, after this line it opens AppDelegate class file and throws and error. I'll try to migrate from swift 2.2 again, maybe this will help.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint. You will get more information.

Comment: It didn't help. I have no clue what causes this error.
If i put an exception breakpoint it shows me Thread 1 Breakpoint 1.2 error.

Comment: You cannot use a custom class as a Core Data attribute unless you archive the instance(s). An alternative is to make the custom class also a CoreData entity.

Comment: I used to do it before I updated to Swift 3. 
Code before update was:
entity.shapes = shapes.
After updating to Swift 3 xCode updated it like so:
entity.shapes = shapes as NSObject.

So the only thing changed is the part 'as NSObject'

Comment: The migrator is not perfect. Do not trust it unconditionally. `NSObject` is a kind of common denominator. Try to cast or use the actual types.

Comment: That's pity. I think there's no option other than using archiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it.
The problem was in decoding my custom NSObject subclass.

```
aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "number") as? Int
```

**decodeObject** didn't return me an integer value, but I discovered that **decodeInteger** method does it.

```
aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "column")
```

However, **decodeInteger** method sometimes caused a crash as well, so I ended up with the next condition:

```
var n = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "number") as? Int
if n == nil {
    n = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "number")
}
```